# direct-state-acces [sic] tag should be direct-state-access

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I was told to raise this on meta so that is what I am doing.  The question title says it all:

> [direct-state-acces](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct-state-acces) [sic] tag should be [direct-state-access](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct-state-access)

The error I get when I try to update to the correct spelling says:

> You are trying to create the tag `direct-state-access` however `direct-state-acces` already exists! If you think the new tag should be allowed discuss on meta.

Comment: You have the privilege to create a new tag (as shown when you asked that question) and you should be able to edit your question to rename the tag directly. May I know the issue you faced? Was it an error due to similar existing tag name?

Comment: @AndrewT. See updated question.

Comment: I've fixed the tag's spelling. The old tag should [get deleted automatically at 03:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/246175).